# Steering twitch?

Tags: chevrolet, power-steering, cruze, eps

On a test drive of a 2016 Chevy Cruze, the steering wheel seemed to be ... 'twitching'.  Just little jumps.  We were going ~40 mph on a straight, smooth, road.  There was no pulling, or any other discernible problem.  When I later drove the same route in my own car, there was not disturbance.

Assuming I didn't just imagine this, what might be the cause?  The Cruze has some form of Electrical Power Steering.  (EPS)

Comment: The steering system may have suffered damaged and/or the torque sensor is faulty. Calibration may correct this or advanced diagnosis is needed to determine where fault lies. Electric power steering use brushed motors that wear out after a long life. Electronics can fail or become intermittent at any time.